# Перестраивается ли индекс автоматически?

Tags: sql, oracle, table, index, oracle19c

В литературе часто можно встретить утверждение о том, что многочисленные индексы замедляют вставку, так как им приходится перестраиваться. В документации описание этого не нашел.

Проэкспериментировал, но перестройки индекса после вставки так и не обнаружил. Где же истина?

```
create table t 
(
    i int,
    str varchar2(100)
);

select * from t;

create index t_ind on t(i, str);

select * from all_indexes where index_name = 'T_IND'; 

insert into t
select level, dbms_random.string('X', 60) from dual connect by level < 1e3;

commit;

-- Данные по индексу (blevel, leaf_blocks) все еще пусты (0)

alter index t_ind rebuild;

-- Теперь значения изменились
```

Comment: Им приходится обновлятся, не  перестраиваться это разные вещи.

Comment: А каким образом обновляться? Это не должно отражаться в статистике индекса? Как можно это проверить, не подскажете?

Comment: Обновлятся - значит будут добавлятся/изменятся/удалятся записи в индексе.    Статистика не собирается сразу же. После массовых изменений, так: `exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, 't', cascade=>true) `

Comment: Большое количество индексов может замедлять работау БД. От ненужных / неиспользуемых индексов лучше избавиться. Кроме того существуют разраяд индексов - BITMAP, которые могут сильно замедлять работу в случае параллельных изменений. Но это тема для отдельного вопроса)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> многочисленные индексы замедляют вставку, так как им приходится перестраиваться.

Это неверное утверждение (возможно машинный перевод). Индексы никогда не перестраиваются (*rebuild*) при выполнении DML, они изменяются в соответствии с изменениями записей в таблице.

Некоторые столбцы в представлениях:

```
(user|all|dba)_indexes (..., num_rows,blevel,leaf_blocks,...)
```

, отражают статистику собранную по индексу.

Сбор статистики не происходит сразу же после изменения индекса, а выполняется регулярно, [как описано здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/gathering-optimizer-statistics.html#GUID-F007E78A-9967-4921-8046-D8F59A9272B4).

После массовых изменений в таблице рекомендуется вручную [собрать статистику по таблице](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/optimizer-statistics-concepts.html#GUID-CA59EF6A-66D2-4BF8-B1F9-85EC5CA3C81F). С параметром `cascade=>true` будет собрана также статистика по всем индексам таблицы.

```sql
create table t1 (i int, str varchar2 (100))
/
create index t1_ind on t1 (i, str);
/
prompt  &_date
2020-05-15 13:15:38

insert into t1
select level, dbms_random.string('X', 60) from dual connect by level <= 1e3;
commit;

select num_rows, blevel, leaf_blocks, last_analyzed 
from user_indexes where index_name = upper ('t1_ind'); 

  NUM_ROWS     BLEVEL LEAF_BLOCKS LAST_ANALYZED      
---------- ---------- ----------- -------------------
         0          0           0 2020-05-15 13:15:36
```

В столбеце `LAST_ANALYZED` время создания индекса, не массовой вставки. Сбор статистики:

```sql
exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats (user, 't1', cascade=>true)

select num_rows, blevel, leaf_blocks, last_analyzed 
from user_indexes where index_name = upper ('t1_ind'); 

  NUM_ROWS     BLEVEL LEAF_BLOCKS LAST_ANALYZED      
---------- ---------- ----------- -------------------
      1000          1          10 2020-05-15 13:17:48
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое. Как всегда объективно и по делу.